# How Sitemap PHP TO XML as LINK

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

The following code is for the **SITEMAP** and I wrote it in **PHP** and I've converted it to **XML** by file **'.htaccess'**.

*.htaccess*

```
## Sitemap.php To Sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

*sitemap.php*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84 
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84/sitemap.xsd">
<HEADLINE><BYLINE>XML Sitemap Index : </BYLINE></HEADLINE>
<url>
   <loc><a href="http://www.sample.com">http://www.sample.com</a></loc>
   <changefreq>Always</changefreq>
   <priority>1.0</priority>
   <lastmod></lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

See also: `http://s6.picofile.com/file/8380482426/link_sitemap.jpg`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YffSq.jpg)

For example See that **Yoast**, In Table **sitemap** clicks the **link**.
When I click the **link**, It opens the page.

I want to click this code below and Open that **link** as a page.

```
<loc><a href="http://www.sample.com">http://www.sample.com</a></loc>
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: These are HMTL Sitemaps. You can check the following link. https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/html-sitemap.html

Comment: I know but, When I click a link and it opens as a page with a new tab.
**<url><loc><a target="_blank" href="http://www.sample.com">http://www.sample.com</a></loc></url>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal XML sitemap for your web site should look like :

```
       <urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
    <loc>your URL1</loc>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
    <loc>your URL2</loc>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    ...
    </urlset>
```

or just generate one for your web at https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Or create a PHP script which will directly output a XML file with the same structure. No need to use htaccess then. Just use headers in php like this:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
```

Comment: I know but, When I click a link and it opens as a page with a new tab.
**<url><loc><a target="_blank" href="http://www.sample.com">http://www.sample.com</a></loc></url>**
It doesn't work.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but why?  The XML sitemap links are not intended to have such behavior, it is just for indexing your pages. But if the target _blank is not working, maybe try with JS like this: javascript:window.open, but that will probably not work in XML itself. If you need all your pages listed on your web, then just parse your XML file with PHP and show the URL list and then the target blank will work, but I don't think it will work from XML sitemap as it is just the list of pages for search engine indexing.

Comment: Yes it is true that the page is indexed for search engines
But I want the page to be graphic and responsive
Like this: http://s7.picofile.com/file/8380853018/sitemap_xml.png